# Powershell Registry Select Property PackageName

Tags: powershell

using the following but can't seem to get what I need

```
 gci HKCR:\Installer\Patches\*\SourceList\
```

which gives

```
 Hive: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Patches\FD74B7292B19FBE4B966342B9CE514FB


 Name                           Property                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 ----                           --------                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 SourceList                     PackageName : proof-fr-fr.MSP
```

Would like to be able to only display the Packagename that matches "SU"

Example Data in the Registry

```
 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\patches\04F6053220AFAEA4E842F45C506D9FDF\SourceList]
 "PackageName"="ICUserApps_64bit_SU5(SU5-IC-116915).msp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Get-ItemProperty` (alias: `gp`) to get registry key properties.

```
Get-ChildItem HKCR:\Installer\Patches\*\SourceList| 
    where {(Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath).PackageName -match'su'}
```

Edit:
To grab only the package name, you could use:

```
Get-ChildItem HKCR:\Installer\Patches\*\SourceList| 
    foreach {(Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath).PackageName}|
    where {$_ -match 'su'}
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to only pull out the PackageName?